# jQuery add css value incrementally 

Tags: jquery

I want to add or subtract the value of 'top' in this css change. Rather then specifying a specific ammount of pixels I would like to add 20px to the current value provided by the external css.

The goal is to make the list move up an down.

```
$('.up').click(function(){
   $('.list').css('top','-20px');
});
```

the HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <ul class="list">
        <li >first item</li>
        <li class="active">second item</li>
        <li>third item</li>
        <li >fourth item</li>
    <ul>
</div>   
<a href="#" class="up">up</a>
<a href="#" class="up">down</a>​
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Based on your edit:**

```
$('.up').click(function(){
   $('.list').css({position:'absolute', top: parseInt($('.list').css('top'), 10) + 20 + 'px'});
});
```

Or you can add `20px` with each click while using `animate` like this:

```
$('.up').click(function(){
   $('.list').css({position:'absolute'});
   $('.list').animate({top: '+=20'});
});
```

---

The `top` property wont work unless you also specify `position`:

```
$('.up').click(function(){
   $('.list').css({position:'absolute', top:'-20px'});
});
```

Change `position` to `absolute` or `relative` as per your needs.

Note that if you want the `.list` element appear only inside its container while changing `top`, you need to assign `position:relative` to parent element and `absolute` to `.list` element.

Answer (score 9):

The `.css()` method also allows the "+=" and "-=" syntax that `.animate()` takes. So you can simply do this:

```
$('.up').click(function(){
   $('.list').css('top','-=20px');
});
```

Comment: This should be the best answer imo.

Answer (score 1):

See this JSFiddle for a complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/NYVmw/

```
$('.up').click(function(){
    var newtop = $('.list').position().top - 20;
    $('.list').css('top', newtop + 'px');
});

$('.down').click(function(){
    var newtop = $('.list').position().top + 20;
    $('.list').css('top', newtop + 'px');
});
```

​

Comment: wow, I thought I knew what I wanted to do, but this was a game changer for me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Change your 'up' class into different id's for the buttons

```
<a href="#" id="up">up</a>
<a href="#" id="down">down</a>​
```

Take the current value of container's margin-top and modify it :

```
$('#up').on('click', function(){
  currentValue = parseInt($('#container').css("margin-top"));
  currentValue -= amount;
  $('#container').css("margin-top", currentValue)
})

$('#down').on('click', function(){
  currentValue = parseInt($('#container').css("margin-top"));
  currentValue += amount;
  $('#container').css("margin-top", currentValue)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS isn't really for doing math and operations, but more for just specifying your styles. The best way to do it would be to, in javascript,

```
getElementById("nameofyourelement").style['top'] = "5px"
```

for example. Using CSS3 animations would even be better. Like this

```
getElementById("nameofyourelement").style['-webkit-transition-duration'] = "1s" //1 second duration for animation, set to 0 if you don't want animation
getElementById("nameofyourelement").style['-webkit-transform'] = "translateY(5px)"
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('.list').css('position','relative').css('top','-20px');`

Comment: wrong way of writing jQuery, You could have merged css functions. `$('.list').css({'position':'relative', 'top':'-20px'});`

Comment: I just want to put more attention on `position`. and also, its not a WRONG way, it works as well

Comment: yes it will generate the correct result, but do you prefer the same to be used in your project?? it is a wrong idea of calling same function twice, whereas it can be done in one.